# How to print the value of Enum which is passed as parameter in the function in Java?

Tags: java, enums

My requirement is I want to pass the Enum as the parameter in the function,and from the function want to print the value of Enum. For Example Enum, Category.ONE should print 1. Similarly for TWO should print 2 and for THREE should print 3.

I assigned the value Enum, like 1, 2, 3.

```
enum Category {
    ONE(1),
    TWO (2),
    THREE(3);

    private final Integer num;

    Category(Integer val) {
        num = val;
    }

}

public class EnumDemo1 {
    public static void printEnumValue(Category category){
        System.out.println(category.name()); // Want to print the value of ENUM. 1, 2, 3
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for(Category category: Category.values()){
            printEnumValue(category);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a getter for the `num` field in the enum, or make the field public

Comment: If you just want "1 2 3" you might be able to get by with `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a method that returns `num`, e.g.:

```
enum Category {
    ONE(1),
    TWO (2),
    THREE(3);

    private final Integer num;

    Category(Integer val) {
        num = val;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return num;
    }
}
```

And then, call it from `printEnumValue`, e.g.:

```
public static void printEnumValue(Category category){
    System.out.println(category.getValue()); // Want to print the value of ENUM. 1, 2, 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a getter for the field, or make it public:

```
enum Category {
    ONE(1),
    TWO (2),
    THREE(3);

    private final Integer num;

    Category(Integer val) {
        num = val;
    }
    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }
}

public class EnumDemo1 {
     public static void printEnumValue(Category category){
         System.out.println(category.getNum()); // Want to print the value of ENUM. 1, 2, 3
     }
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for(Category category: Category.values()){
            printEnumValue(category);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, enums have `ordinals`, which return an integer, describing the order of the enum value.

Answer (score -2):

remove `final` modifier for num field and declare getter method

```java
enum Category {
    ONE(1),
    TWO (2),
    THREE(3);
    // 
    private Integer num;

    Category(Integer val) {
        this.num = val;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return num;
    }
}

public class EnumDemo1 {
     public static void printEnumValue(Category category){
         System.out.println(category.getValue()); // Want to print the value of ENUM. 1, 2, 3
     }
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for(Category category: Category.values()){
            printEnumValue(category);
        }
    }
}
```

see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html for more

Comment: the advice to remove `final` is irrilevant and the getter declaration was already pointed out 20 minutes before